# auto scale Element to fit viewport, when not 100% visible

Tags: javascript, math, transform, scale, gsap

my goal is to auto scale an element proportional - it’s about 40% visible in viewport (from Bottom) - with `transform: scale(scaleFactor)` to fit the viewport, based on the current viewport `width` and `height`.

My Code looks something like this:

```html
<div class="wrapper relative">
   <figure id="scaleContainer">
      <img id="hardware" class="absolute block" src="path/to/image.jpg">
      <img id="screen" class="absolute block" src="path/to/image.jpg">
    </figure>
</div>
```

So how can i calculate the `scaleFactor` and the `transformOrigin` to scale the screen-image to fit the current viewport?

Background: I have a scroll-based scale Animation, similar to the [Apple Catalina Website](http://apple.com/macos/catalina). The animation looks the same with me. The only question is: How can I calculate the `scaleFactor` and `transformOrigin` dynamically so that my screen-image is centered and covers the whole screen at the beginning.

my gsap.timeline looks like this:

```js
let timeline = gsap.timeline({ paused:true });
timeline.fromTo('#scaleContainer', {scale: scaleFactor}, {scale: 1});
```

Note: I want to calculate the `transformOrigin` on the `y-axis`, because the figure tag is not centered in the viewport, so `transform-origin: center` or `transform-origin: 50% 50%` will not work.

How can I best solve this? Thanks for your answers and your ideas

Comment: Please show a *minimal* demo with your code so far. This depends on your element's positioning and when you want the animation to kick in (or is its progress attached completely to the scroll position?).

Comment: @ZachSaucier here is a link to my current state: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-stallman-vgt4y

Comment: Use proportions: `var horizScale = window.innerWidth / elem.offsetWidth;`